# List images in directory, but exclude subdirectories

Tags: r, directory

I would like to get a list of all images in a certain directory, but there is also a subdirectory. With the following code all files are correctly included, but the subdirectory is the first entry in the variable "all_files":

```
all_files <- list.files ("C:/absolute_directory/plots", include.dirs = FALSE)
print (all_files)

#output
# [1]subdirectory # <- I want to exclude this subdirectory
# [2]correctpicture1.jpg
# [3]correctpicture2.jpg
# [4]correctpicture3.jpg
# [5]correctpicture4.jpg
# [6]correctpicture5.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could solve it. `pattern="\\.jpg$"` means all files ending with `.jpg`.

```
all_files <- list.files("C:/absolute_directory/plots", pattern="\\.jpg$")
```

Comment: To my knowledge the \\ is redundant here.

Comment: Why and what do you think it should be?

Comment: I think you are making a mistake. `pattern` argument is a regex and so `.jpg$` does not mean *dot* followed by *jpg* but rather *any* character followed by *jpg* (at the end of a piece of text). This is because `.` (dot) in regex has a special meaning (it is a placeholder for any character except the end-of-the line character, `\n`) and to use it in the literal sense, you need to escape it. Try `grepl(pattern="\\.jpg$", x=c("ajpg", ".jpg"))` and `grepl(pattern=".jpg$", x=c("ajpg", ".jpg"))` and check the output, you will understand the difference.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will have a look at it!